# Select Multiple slices from Numpy array at once

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I want to implement a vectorized SGD algorithm and would like to generate multiple mini batches at once.

Suppose `data = np.arange(0, 100)`, `miniBatchSize=10`, `n_miniBatches=10` and `indices = np.random.randint(0, n_miniBatches, 5)` (5 mini batches). What I would like to achieve is

```
miniBatches = np.zeros(5, miniBatchSize)
for i in range(5):
     miniBatches[i] = data[indices[i]: indices[i] + miniBatchSize]
```

Is there any way to avoid for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to do some sort of Python level loop.  You can combine slices as you do here, or you can generate index ranges, concatenate those, and one indexing.  Speeds about the same for all alternatives.  One other option is to generate all slices of this size with `as_strided`, and select a subset.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [stride tricks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

a = as_strided(data[:n_miniBatches], shape=(miniBatchSize, n_miniBatches), strides=2*data.strides, writeable=False)    
miniBatches = a[:, indices].T


# E.g. indices = array([0, 7, 1, 0, 0])
Output:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]])
```